# std::atomic_uint16_t or std::atomic_uint64_t for this value that will overflow

Tags: c++

```
std::atomic_uint64_t gCounter = 0;

constexpr size_t MaxItems = 4096;
constexpr size_t Mask     = MaxItems - 1u;

// Get an index, from 0-4095, in round-robin fashion.
uint16_t GetIndex() {
    return gCounter++ & Mask;
}
```

While reviewing this code I wrote, I'm wondering if it's more memory/speed efficient to use a `std::atomic_uint16_t`, instead of a `std::atomic_uint64_t` for the code above, since the value returned by GetIndex() is in the range [0, 4095]. If it weren't using atomic, I would use uint16_t for gCounter, but since this is dealing with atomics, I'm just not sure.

Comment: This will vary per CPU, but I would assume that 16-bit writes vs 64-bit writes will be the same for any 64-bit system.  And honestly, 16/64 bit non atomic will probably be identical in terms of perf as well (again assuming 64-bit CPU words.)  I've actually found that using 16-bit often decreases performance as it occasionally adds the need to and off high bits in registers and such.

Answer (score 1):

Turning into an answer, because it is:

This will vary per CPU, but I would assume that 16-bit writes vs 64-bit writes will be the same for any 64-bit system. And honestly, 16/64 bit non atomic will probably be identical in terms of perf as well (again assuming 64-bit CPU words.) I've actually found that using 16-bit often decreases performance as it occasionally adds the need to and off high bits in registers and such.

<strike>That code worries me for other reasons. You are doing 4 operations: a load, and, increment, store. I don't know of many systems (any honestly) that can do those all atomically so this probably becomes a lock/unlock of some sort. This would so overpower 16/64 bit writes as to be absurd.</strike>

My worries were unfounded as the and does not store to memory so therefore no lock or try read/write loop is needed.

But still:

You can check your assembly output to be sure that you are getting what you expect.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you find worrisome. The postfix ++ operation is defined for the atomic, so what's the problem? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith

Comment: For the record, the postfix increment operation on atomic integers is supported without locks on basically every system. On x86 (since the 486), there is a dedicated instruction, `xadd` (with a `lock` prefix) that adds a register to a memory location while loading the original value of the memory into the register atomically. On other systems, this could be implemented with a loop over compare and swap, or over load link/store conditional (on systems with load link/store conditional, almost all atomic operations are implemented in terms of those instructions). No full on locking needed.

Comment: As to the post-increment, I was having issues with the algorithm itself, which I since deleted because I was misunderstanding what you were trying to do.  And because the and is not stored back to memory, the simple atomic will work fine.  Again, I was thinking you were trying to mask the counter into a range and store to memory, which is incorrect.